# Solr admin giving 404 error

Tags: java, tomcat, xpath, solr, centos

I am trying to start solr on tomcat on my centos production server . I have it already working on the local . However , when I try to access the admin , I get the 404 error (missing core name in path) . I am just trying to set up the example solr application with single core first , I haven't deployed a single line of code from my local work (This is just to ensure that the basic set up is done correctly) .I started looking at logs (catalina.out and catalina.log) , found the following errors logged in there :

```
SEVERE: Error processing TLD files for context path /manager
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI "file:./" is not hierarchical

SEVERE: Error processing TLD files for context path /solr
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI "file:./" is not hierarchical

SEVERE: Error in xpath:javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpressionException: multiple nodes in  node-set

SEVERE: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Error in xpath:/config/indexConfig/text() for solrconfig.xml

Caused by: javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpressionException: multiple nodes in node-set
```

in that order . I have followed the solr wiki on this one completely and added relevant paths where necessary . I can post the config files as well , however since they are just examples (out of the box) it won't be any different .

I am not versed with java at all and can't figure out what the error is about .

This is the config for the server :

```
<Context allowlinking="true" crosscontext="true" debug="0" docbase="/var/lib/tomcat6/my/solr.war" priviledged="true">
<Environment name="solr/home" override="true" type="java.lang.String" value="       </var/lib/tomcat6/solr/>">
 </Context>
```

Comment: Please post the config, this is due to you specifying the wrong filepath for you solrconfig I think

Comment: Which exact config are you requesting ? The tomcat server config or the solr one ?

Comment: The tomcat config to start with, please :)

Comment: You can have a look , added the config file for the tomcat server to know what solr home is .

Comment: I am able to land on "Welcome to Solr" home page . This means my solr home is recognized correctly , right ?

Answer (score 4):

So after hours of digging into catlina.out , the error was related to java version . I had java 1.5 on the server and 1.6 on local . Switching to 1.6 on production server did the trick.

Comment: Just had exactly the same thing with TomCat6 on a CentOS 6 box. Resolved it by doing "yum install java-1.6.0" as the default is 1.5.0.